# How to create a private ethereum network

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereumjs

I want to understand how to create a private blockchain using ethereum and create a minable coin. Also, I want to know if I can modify the consensus algorithm that runs on every node?

There are another two questions:

- Can a private network cryptocurrency be sold or integrated with exchanges for trading?
- Up to what level can I customize the ethereum blockchain and create my own, like TRON did?

Comment: Please, split your questions into multiple posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple tutorials on how to create a private Ethereum network, like [this one](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-137ab15989c6).

Now, if you want to customize the consensus algorithm and other features, you might want to download the [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) source code and change it as you need. Maybe you'll want to ask independent questions on how to change some thing or another in the code, after doing some research by yourself of course.

Answering your other two questions,

- Yes, you can integrate your private blockchain to an exchange. Of course you will have to fullfil their requirements on doing so.
- You can customize every single aspect of it as it is open source.